# How to connect Al to Cu wire

Tags: electrical

I just replace a 42 year old electric range.  The supply line was Al, and the pigtail from the old range was CU.  They were connected in a junction box with gray colored wire nuts.  The connection appeared to be in very good shape without any corrosion or oxidation as might be expected.  The replacement range had the same size copper stranded pigtail.  I connected the same way and it appears to be OK but seems I've heard bad stories about connecting to copper to Aluminium in this manner.  Will this be OK?

Answer (score 4):

Aluminum wire is bad. It will prank call your friends, and steal your girlfriend.

No seriously, you just need to make sure you are terminating it properly and use splices specifically designed for aluminum wire connections.  These must have a rating of CO/ALR (COpper/ALuminum Revised).

Now to go deeper into the ooga-booga-scary aluminum wire.  Where it got into big trouble was trying to use it for the thin wires used in outlet and lighting circuits (14/12 AWG copper, 12/10 AWG aluminum).  This was originally done due to the scarcity of metals in post-WWII reconstruction.  They made hasty choices of aluminum alloy and termination design, and it didn't work and caused fires.  They solved it three ways:

- improved the terminations (now CO-ALR).
- improved the aluminum alloy (banned AA-1350 and now require AA-80xx)
- Stopped using it for the thin stuff (12/10 AWG) since there isn't much cost savings.

I prefer copper up to 6 AWG/50A, and aluminum above that.

You might consider replacing your electric cable to your range, for a totally different reason: you probably have 3-wire (hot-neutral-hot), no ground. Any problem with the neutral wire will electrify the chassis of the range and kill you.  It happens.  Ground can be retrofitted separately, but why not seize the chance to dump the archaic AA-13xx cable.

Comment: Umm because replacing it would cost the average person $1000 - at least.  The wire performed for all of these years and it needs to be replaced because of a new stove?

Comment: @DMoore depends on the topology of house and wiring.  .  Some retrofits are easy.